# how can i make OpenAI API to summarize a text giving it a percent to reduce the original text length?

Tags: prompt, openai-api

I want to summarize a given text to a user selected percentage (25%, 50%, 75%). For example, if the user selects 25%, that means, summarize to a 25% the original text length, if the original text is 1000 words long, summarize it to 250 words.
The problem is, the OpenAI API receives the prompt but when selecting and changing different percentages, the API returns the same range of length words:

This is an example text:
"World War II or the Second World War, often abbreviated as WWII or WW2, was a global conflict that lasted from 1939 to 1945. The vast majority of the world's countries, including all of the great powers, fought as part of two opposing military alliances: the Allies and the Axis. Many participants threw their economic, industrial, and scientific capabilities behind this total war, blurring the distinction between civilian and military resources. Aircraft played a major role, enabling the strategic bombing of population centres and the delivery of the only two nuclear weapons ever used in war. World War II was by far the deadliest conflict in history, resulting in an estimated 70 to 85 million fatalities, mostly among civilians. Tens of millions died due to genocides (including the Holocaust), starvation, massacres, and disease. In the wake of Axis defeat, Germany, Austria and Japan were occupied, and war crimes tribunals were conducted against German and Japanese leaders."

This text is 985 characters long.

This is the input i made:

"
Summerize next text a with this indication:
-Return a response in the language of the input text.
-Return a response using other words.
-Reduce the original text length to a 25%:

World War II or the Second World War, often abbreviated as WWII or WW2, was a global conflict that lasted from 1939 to 1945. The vast majority of the world's countries, including all of the great powers, fought as part of two opposing military alliances: the Allies and the Axis. Many participants threw their economic, industrial, and scientific capabilities behind this total war, blurring the distinction between civilian and military resources. Aircraft played a major role, enabling the strategic bombing of population centres and the delivery of the only two nuclear weapons ever used in war. World War II was by far the deadliest conflict in history, resulting in an estimated 70 to 85 million fatalities, mostly among civilians. Tens of millions died due to genocides (including the Holocaust), starvation, massacres, and disease. In the wake of Axis defeat, Germany, Austria and Japan were occupied, and war crimes tribunals were conducted against German and Japanese leaders.
"

The text response length is 624 characters which should be 246 because i gave 25% summarizer. No matter what percent i gave to the API, it always returns the same range of words that equals almost 50%.

This is my chatGPT config:

```
export async function generateChatResponse(prompt: string): Promise<string> {
  try {
    console.log(prompt)
    const response = await axios.post(
      API_BASE_URL,
      {
        messages: [
          {
            role: 'user',
            content: prompt
          }
        ],
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        max_tokens: 150,
        temperature: 0.7,
        stop: '\n',
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
        },
      }
    );
    console.log(response)
    return response.data.choices[0].message.content.trim();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error generating chat response:', error);
    return 'Oops! An error occurred while processing your request.';
  }
}
```

How can i make the API to "obey" the percent input to reduce the original text length?

I tried changing the `max_tokens: 150` to `max_tokens: 500` but it has no significative difference.
I tried changing the prompt to make it more specific but i returns the same range of words.